# Executing gradle scripts from external directories

Tags: gradle, groovy

I need to execute groovy script with gradle, but the thing is that these scripts are located in external directory (let's say it's Desktop). I've heard, that in previous versions of Gradle (currently working on 3.2.1) it was not possible, since it is not part of the gradle project. I wonder if it is possible now, or do I have to copy all these scripts into some folder located in gradle project, to execute it.

User story:

- I found script in external directory (based on some properties passed to console) - I have absolute path to the script
- Now I want to execute this script (`build.gradle`) without copying it into my gradle project

I'm pretty green with gradle and I hope I made my point clear.

Thanks for help and every attempt :)

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 2):

Is [that](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/42556631) what you're looking for? To run the script clone the repository, navigate to `42556631/project` folder and run the command:

```
gradle -b ../script/build.gradle clean build
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you need to move build.gradle file into project/Build Script folder and then run it.